# How to use 2 models in class base View that is Home view and Detailview

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have two model `Item` and `Women`
this is the code for my 2 models

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Women(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        price = models.FloatField()
        discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
        label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
        slug = models.SlugField()
        description = models.TextField()
        image = models.ImageField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

In my `view.py`
I have created `Homeview(View)` to render the `homepage.html` which I have used `get_context_data` to render the two model which is the `Item` and `Women`.

this is code for my `views.py`

```py
class HomeView(ListView):
       
     template_name='Ecommerce/home-page.html'
    
     def get_queryset(self):
         return Item.objects.all()
    
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):    
         et =super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         et['Item_qs']= Item.objects.all()
         et['women_qs']= Women.objects.all()
         return et
  

class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
      model= Women,Item
      template_name='Ecommerce/product-page.html'
```

i dont know if i am writing the `ProductDetailView` correctly for the 2 models

Now within the homepage my first div I used the `Item` model to loop through
And my second div I used the `Women` model to loop through

this is how i rendered the two views in my html templates
the first one is for the item model

```html
     {% for item in Item_qs %}
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
              
                  <!--Card image-->
                  <div class="view overlay">
                    <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" class="card-img-top"
                      alt="">
                    <a href="{{item.get_absolute_url}}">
                      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <!--Card image-->
    
                </div>
                <!--Card-->
    {% end%}
```

and this is for the Women model

```html
    {% for items in women_qs %}
              <!--Grid column-->
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    
                <!--Card-->
                <div class="card zoom">
    
                  <!--Card image-->
                  <div class="view overlay">
                    <img src="{{ items.image.url }}" class="card-img-top"
                      alt="">
                    <a href="{{items.get_absolute_url}}">
                      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                
                </div>
                <!--Card-->
    
              </div>
               {% endfor %}
```

i am using get_absoulte_url as the href link to get the Productpage.html
below is the code

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("Ecommerce:product", kwargs={
             'slug': self.slug    })
```

My problem is how do I create a `ProductDetailpage(Detailview)` to get the details of individual items that is in the Item model and the Women model?
And how do I render both in the template
Please I believe my question is clear enough and if anyone need clarification I can explain further.
Looking forward for your assistance house

Comment: Post some code to try to explain/illustrate what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can't use `DetailView` with multiple models. You'd be better off writing a normal `View` and allowing the URL for it take 2 params for each of your models.

Then you can get each instance in your view.

It'd work something like this;

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:item_id>/<int:women_id>', MultiModelView.as_view()),
]
```

```py
class MultiModelView(View):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """ Constructor """
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.item_id = None
        self.women_id = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.item_id = self.kwargs.get('item_id')
        self.women_id = self.kwargs.get('women_id')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'item': Item.objects.get(id=self.item_id),
            'woman': Women.objects.get(id=self.women_id),
        })
        return context
```

Comment: Here I created a function get_absolute_url to get the Productpage.html  can I still use it to serve as the href  link? For both instance?

Comment: @proflord you've not shown what your `get_absolute_url` does, so I can only assume that you can use it because you'd have 2 instances of the objects

Comment: def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("Ecommerce:product", kwargs={
             'slug': self.slug    }) this is what am using to get the productpage template buh since you are using the int to get the two id i am getting Reverse for 'product' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'women'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product(?P<item_id>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<women_id>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Comment: If you want a link to get to a page for 2 objects, you'll have to create it in the template where you've got the two IDs available. `get_absolute_url` is meant to get you a link to that object really, unless you customise things.